# Circular drawing is not cleared at 90 degrees

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval

I want to move a red circle on orbit with 360 degrees.

But at 90 degrees, the circle is not cleared.

Code is here: **https://jsfiddle.net/Laqd0L36/3/**

```
var i=0;

 function Rotate(ctx){
     i++;          
     if(i==360){                              
         i=0;
     }
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
 //Radius of orbit * i(degree) * convert to radian
     x = 140*Math.cos(i*Math.PI/180);
     y = 140*Math.sin(i*Math.PI/180);
     Circle(ctx,x,y);
     }

 function Circle(ctx,x,y){
     ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,35,55)';
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x,y,12,0,Math.PI*2,true);
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.closePath();
     }

 function CtxInterval(){
     var can = document.getElementById("can");
     var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
     ctx.translate(150,150);
     setInterval(function(){Rotate(ctx);},10);
 }
 CtxInterval();
```

Comment: Why do you wanna use unnecessary HTML tags, while typing your question?

Comment: Remove `ctx.translate(150, 150)`, and add `150` to `x` and `y`in `arc()`. [A fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ud9v2dcL/).

Answer (score 1):

As you are translating your context by `150, 150`, you need to start your `clearRect` rectangle at `-150, -150`.
(Here is your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Laqd0L36/4/) )

@Teemu's comment is more elegant solution though i.e.

> Remove `ctx.translate(150, 150)`, and add 150 to x and y in `arc()`

```
 var i=0;

 function Rotate(ctx){
     i++;          
     if(i==360){                              
         i=0;
     }
     console.log("width: "+ctx.canvas.width+ "height: "+ctx.canvas.height);
     ctx.clearRect(-150,-150,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);

 //Radius of orbit * i(degree) * convert to radian
     x = 140*Math.cos(i*Math.PI/180);
     y = 140*Math.sin(i*Math.PI/180);
     Circle(ctx,x,y);
     }

 function Circle(ctx,x,y){
     ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,35,55)';
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(x,y,12,0,Math.PI*2,true);
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.closePath();
     }

 function CtxInterval(){
     var can = document.getElementById("can");
     var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
     ctx.translate(150,150);
     setInterval(function(){Rotate(ctx);},10);
 }
 CtxInterval();
```